# How to create Client working on both UDP and TCP in the same port C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, udpclient

When I use the next code at client side:

```
IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8001);
UdpClient UDPServer = new UdpClient(EndPoint);
TcpClient TCPClient = new TcpClient(EndPoint);
```

I got an exception, that it is allowed to use only single socket address. But at the server side I use:

```
IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8001);
TcpListener TcpServer = new TcpListener(EndPoint);
UdpClient UDPServer = new UdpClient(EndPoint);
```

And there is no exception. Why?

I need to write a client that can be work on both TCP and UDP protocols in the same port. TCP - for general commands, UDP - for voice stream. How to do this?

Comment: I think that would be wrong. The OS would not give you two handles to one endpoint.

Comment: It works at server side with TcpListener and UdpClient classes. I can receive a data both on UDP and TCP at the same port

Comment: Well, That`s weird...

Comment: Why do you care what port the client binds to? Also, if you're binding to 127.0.0.1, does that mean the server and client are running on the same machine? If so, then how are you expecting them to both bind to the same TCP port? And how will you keep the client from connecting to itself?

Comment: If i do not bind UDP client I can't receive data in. When I try to use Bytes = UDPClient.Receive(ref RemoteEndPoint); I have an axception that i must firstly bind it

Comment: David Schwartz you was write. The problem was that i started client and server on the same machine. Thanks!

Comment: @Sergey post the finding as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I triyed to bind UDPClient object to the same port number on Client side and as well as at Server side. That's why a I had an exception.

Comment: Please post an actual answer instead of repeating a comment that inspired you to find the answer.